# SQL 2008 reporting services with SQL 2005 server

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ssrs

Is it a supported configuration to be run a SQL 2008 reporting services server with a SQL 2005 database server?

Either way, where can I find supporting documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'll need to use a SQL 2008 server for the ReportingServices database.  You can connect SSRS 2008 to pull data from a SQL 2005 server without issue.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction so I can view supporting documentation? ( our answer is what I remember reading, and its what I told my mgr, but I havn't been able to find docs )

Comment: I'm finding a surprising lack of info confirming this.  I saw something that says that if you want to use Sharepoint mode it requires a SQL 2008 server.  My best suggestion would be to give it a try in a lab and see what happens to be sure.  Then you can become the authorative source.

Comment: Me?!? An authorative source. pish posh. ;-)

I'll look into trying it out and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SQL Server Reporting Services might fail to work successfully even if the database version is different in service pack or build number detail.

In such a case you should upgrade the report server database.

So it is not possible to make it work a 2008 on a 2005 db

For SSRS you can find resources at [SQL Server Reporting Services](http://www.kodyaz.com)

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the answers above yes youo can, check this on sql server 2008 r2.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157300.aspx
(afryer@microsoft.com)